# DNS Aliases of multiple domains in win2k8

Tags: domain-name-system, alias

I have set up a AD integrated server deploying also the role of DNS server. What I want is to put an alias for a specific host of my domain, putting an alias (CNAME) different from the domain name (for example, if the domain is www.mydomain1.com, the alias should be www.domain2.com). Is this possible in Windows Server 2008 and how? Thank you very much in advance.

Kind Regards

Comment: I am not sure what you want.  Can you try to be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like you are saying that your AD domain is `mydomain1.com` and to create a cname from some other domain that points at a resource in your AD integrated domain.

Do you own this other domain?  If so, simply set up this other domain on your DNS server and create a CNAME.